# Ubuntu 17.10 Freezes on Suspend/won't shut down

Tags: suspend, shutdown, 17.10

I have a Lenovo Ideapad y700 14 which I recentually upgraded to 17.10 from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, everything is working fine except the suspend and shut down functions. I have power settings to suspend when I close the lid OR press the power button once. The laptop never ends up suspending and when I open the lid, the screen either remains black OR the purple background from the login screen will be there but nothing else and I have to hold down the power button to turn off the computer. I also cannot shut the computer down as one normally would, as it just hangs at the Ubuntu screen with the orange dots continuously moving.

I put `journalctl -p crit` in the terminal and got this response:

```
CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.free
```

I'm not sure exactly what that means and I've never had an issue like this using Ubuntu. Anyone know how I can go about fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why they release a product without a minimal testing. Ubuntu was much better 6 years ago regarding the basic functionalities.

Comment: Do you have an nvidia card?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [EasyScreenCast](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/690/easyscreencast/) gnome extension installed - try to remove it. 
About that exact error i saw comments on launchpad in which peoples said that EasyScreenCast deletion solved problems for them (and with my own experience - recently installed it and all my system become deadly frozen - so have to remove it from terminal in recovery mode).

Another thing to try is to switch between display managers - from gdm3 to lightdm, for example. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` (install lightdm before via `sudo apt-get install lightdm` if needed). Recently had same log error, after switching from gdm3 to lightdm error had gone.

Comment: much better, merci! yes delete that comment now ...